# Hyperledger Composer CreatePeerCardAdmin is throwing error for unzip

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to enable JWT for hyperledger composer to my blockchain project.

However whilst following the [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn) I came accross the below error. I am not sure what it means:

```
Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
```

when running `./createPeerAdminCard.sh` below is the exact output:

```
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is set to 'hlfv11'
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Using composer-cli at v0.19.5

Successfully created business network card file to
        Output file: /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card

Command succeeded


Successfully imported business network card
        Card file: /tmp/PeerAdmin@hlfv1.card
        Card name: PeerAdmin@hlfv1

Command succeeded

Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? If it is, see http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html
Command failed

Hyperledger Composer PeerAdmin card has been imported, host of fabric specified as 'localhost'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running on a Mac ?

This problem has been seen when there is a hidden file present somewhere in the `~/.comoposer` folder.

If you have cards you need to keep then try a `composer card export` to try and export them, then delete the folder `~/.composer` and re-run the script to create the Peer Admin card.

There are a few details of the problem in this [issue on github](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3645).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am running it on Mac. I will try to attempt your try.